# How do I unmask a folder which was previously masked by a virtual folder called "Desktop"?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, filesystems, desktop

I tried to change my desktop folder from `D:\test4` to `D:\test5`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the last step, I didn't move the files from `D:\test4` to `D:\test5`.

So what happens is that in `D:\`, I have a total of 2 virtual folders, both called `Desktop`:

1. 1 virtual folder `Desktop` which masks (and points to) `D:\test5`
2. 1 virtual folder `Desktop` which masks (and points to) `D:\test4`

[image]

Now the contents of `D:\test4` is no longer showing on my desktop, however it is still being masked by a virtual folder.

Obviously since `D:\test4` is now no longer my *Desktop* folder, I was trying to make it go back to being a "normal folder" (i.e. not masked).

I was wondering how do I unmask it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the desktop.ini file (it's hidden by default) in test4 and the "Desktop" name will be gone.

Comment: amazing how did you know that!

Comment: Because I've had similar situations before :)